# How to access EKS cluster with kubeconfig even when disabling endpoint public access

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks, kubeconfig

So, I am trying to setup an EKS cluster using Terraform EKS Module.

Everything is good, until I try to set the `cluster_endpoint_public_access` to `false`. I can no more access the cluster with my kubeconfig and I can no more applying terraform changes to the cluster with an error "CLUSTER UNREACHABLE".

Is there a solution for this? I forgot maybe something?

It's not possible to set `cluster_endpoint_public_access_cidrs` because it will be so many ips (team members, the Gitlab CI, etc)

Thank you

Comment: Did you already set cluster_endpoint_private_access to true?

Comment: yes private and public access are set to true

Answer (score 0):

you probably are trying to access the cluster from outside the VPC. Since you closed the access from public networks, it is just doing what you told it to.
Try to create EC2 machine in the same VPC, access it by SSH, use the same credentials you did when creating EKS cluster and you should see that the kubeconfig works from that machine.